# Mybatis caching and concurrent modfications

Tags: mybatis

I am using mybatis 3.0.4 for a test against a mysql 5.5 database with mysql-connector JDBC driver, version 5.1.16.

The problem I am experiencing is that if I get a SqlSession via openSession() method and i retrieve data via a select from database, subsequent selects in same session are not aware of changes made (and committed) to database even if i call clearCache() on session. To concurrently modify database I am using Mysql command line client. Setting cacheEnabled as false in configuration file doesn't help too.

I enclose configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>

    <settings>
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false"/>
    </settings>

    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <dataSource type="POOLED">

                <property name="poolMaximumIdleConnections" value="20"></property> 
                <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="80"></property> 
                <property name="poolMaximumCheckoutTime" value="600"></property> 
                <property name="poolTimeToWait" value="600"></property> 


                <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
                <property name="username" value="root"/>
                <property name="password" value="password"/>
            </dataSource>       
        </environment>
    </environments>

    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mappers/TestMapper.xml" />
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Ok, solved by myself. It was not a mybatis issue, it depended on Transaction isolation on JDBC driver, which was by default TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ, I needed TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED instead. Solved with `code` getSessionFactory().openSession(TransactionIsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED);`code`

Comment: move your comment into an answer and mark the question accepted.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved by myself. It was not a mybatis issue, it depended on Transaction isolation on JDBC driver, which was by default TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ, I needed TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED instead. Solved with:

```
getSessionFactory().openSession(TransactionIsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED);
```